# Delphi 6/JEDI-JVCL - Not getting custom message form with detailed stack dump anymore

Tags: delphi, exception, stack, jvcl, jedi

I am using Delphi 6 along with the JEDI-JVCL 3.x.  My project settings include creating the JDBG files and inserting them into the executable.  Yet somewhere along the line I did something that defeated the appearance of the custom Exception handling form that shows the complete detailed stack dump with other information, and now I just get the standard Exception dialog box with just the singular Exception info.  Can anyone tell me most likely what I did that is interfering with the appearance of the custom Exception dialog box?

-- roschler

Comment: it is possible(in some situations) that the exception is not caught correctly therefore it's not able to show you the source of the exception, I do NOT use Jedi stuff but I do use Eureka log(works mostly the same way) and I've been in some situations in which it could NOT find the exception source, very strange...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have deleted Jcl Exception dialog from the project. Or it just initializes later then exception occurs.